# angularjs ui-router parent state

Tags: angularjs

Using angularjs and ui-router can I:

A.) Define custom variables when defining my state (see 'data' below). I currently do this with success, wanted to make sure its proper.

```
.state('parent', {url:'/parent', templateUrl: 'views/parent.html', abstract: true, data: {stuff: 'stuff'}})
```

B.) Have my child state inherit that variable data ( How? )

```
.state('parent.child',   {url:'/child', templateUrl: 'views/parent.child.html', data: parent.data})
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't specify "data" into the child state, is already inherited from parent/abstracted state.
You access it by :

```
$state.current.data
```

Comment: took me a while to get back to the code to test this. I swear i tried it, but I guess not. Works fine!

Comment: did you mean $state.$parent.data ?

Comment: For now, the right object path to the parent item will be $state.$current.parent.